# URLLoader events in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

we can use URLLoader for sending HTTP request and listening events from server. My question is where and how URLLoader dispatches the complete, progress, ioError event? Since in the server side, we do not invoke the dispatchEvent.

code like following:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://example/lookup"));
```

Which object dispatch the aforementioned event, and where does it dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

They are triggered by the virtual machine and originally it occurs (as I guess, I don't sure about this) somewhere in browser implementation of NPAPI (Gecko [API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference) for instance) or PPAPI in chrome.

Comment: @fsbmain-So the XMLHTTPRequest's onreadystatechange also work this way?

Comment: I don't sure about XMLHTTPRequest but it's a part of browser JS engine so it's hardly use the plugin API, more likely option is that both NPAPI and JS engine use the same browser low level methods (that can be handled by browser developer tools or other extensions)

Answer (score 0):

`URLLoader` does it via the HTTP Headers. I'm not overly familiar with HTTP Headers, but I do know the following (from experience plus from reading the LiveDocs):

- `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` is dispatched at a regular interval (predefined within the Flash SDK) so long as progress has been made in the download. It does not dispatch on every byte downloaded nor is there any rhyme or reason as to how it is dispatched, other than what seems to be a regular time interval
- ProgressEvent.PROGRESS event's `bytesTotal` property is taken from the `Content-Length` header. If you send a Range header in the request, it should negate the Content-Length header in the response and you get 0 bytesTotal. You can get around this by listening for `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS_RESPONSE`, looping through the headers, and find Content-Range header. You can use RegEx to get the length from that Object.
- ProgressEvent.PROGRESS event's `bytesLoaded` property is handled internally. URLLoader saves every byte downloaded to a `ByteArray` and the bytesLoaded is simply the ByteArray's `length` property
- I'm unsure how `Event.COMPLETE` fires, but I believe it occurs when the connection is severed.
- `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` is dispatched according to situations predefined internally by the Flash SDK. Most commonly, it will dispatch when a 404 error occurs. Beyond that, I am unsure.

You shouldn't have to do anything server-side except send valid HTTP Headers in each request to make these events fire properly. Everything, for the most part, is handled internally.

I highly suggest reading the [LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html). They are incredibly detailed and still written in a very usable and informative fashion, which is very uncommon for coding documentation